# selecting count(tb2.field_name) based on tb1.id of the table1 and tb2.field

Tags: mysql, select, multipleselection

this question might have been asked before, but I could not find. because I was not able to ask correctly all situations. so pardon me if it is a repeated question. 
I have 2 tables:
tb1 - categories
tb2 - tasks
I want to select all tasks and quantity of tasks by each category.

What I did is this:

```
SELECT category_id, category_title, 
       (SELECT count(task_id) FROM tasks_of_app WHERE category_id ) AS counted_tasks 
FROM categories_of_app
```

but I get all tasks' quantity for each category.

I can't use WHERE because there is not input param.

please, guys help out or tell what book to read to be able to make such kind of queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WHERE category_id` needs to specify what `category_id` should be. You need to match it with the value from the other table to make it a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT category_id, category_title, 
       (SELECT count(task_id) 
        FROM tasks_of_app 
        WHERE tasks_of_app.category_id = categories_of_app.category_id) AS counted_tasks 
FROM categories_of_app
```

But a better way to write this is as a `LEFT JOIN` between the tables.

```
SELECT c.category_id, c.category_title, COUNT(t.task_id) AS counted_tasks
FROM categories_of_app AS c
LEFT JOIN tasks_of_app AS t ON c.category_id = t.category_id
GROUP BY c.category_id
```

Comment: why is the first way of selection bad? I think it is  more understandable to me. Does it affect on performance?

Comment: I think MySQL is not very good at optimizing correlated subqueries, but I could be wrong. In general, joins are the preferred way to relate data between tables.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a column `category_id` in `tasks_of_app` that references the column `category_id` of `categories_of_app` then you need a join and aggregation:

```
SELECT c.category_id, c.category_title, count(t.task_id) counted_tasks 
FROM categories_of_app c LEFT JOIN tasks_of_app t
ON t.category_id = c.category_id
GROUP BY c.category_id, c.category_title
```