# converting from simple mysql to Laravel query constructor

Tags: mysql, laravel

@forpas  guys, I need to the [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59506002/selecting-counttb2-field-name-based-on-tb1-id-of-the-table1-and-tb2-field)  into laravel constructor.

this is what I tried.

```
$cates = DB::table('categories')
           ->select(DB::raw('categories.category_id, categories.category_title, categories.created_at, COUNT(task.task_id) AS counted_tasks'))
           ->leftJoin('tasks', 'categories.category_id', '=', 'tasks.task_cat_id')
           ->get();
```

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause (SQL: select categories.category_id, categories.category_title, categories.created_at, COUNT(task.task_id) AS counted_tasks from `categories` left join `tasks` on `categories`.`category_id` = `tasks`.`task_cat_id`)

Where I can see the final query of the constructor?

Comment: Do you have a `Category` and `Task` model? If so, do you have the relationships between them set up?

Comment: actually, yes. cat table has, cat_id, and task table has cat_if too. so they have a common column to be related.

Comment: If you have the relationships set up in your models you could use `withCount()` i.e. `Category::withCount('tasks')->get();` which by the looks of things would give you what you're after. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `groupBy`. Try this code below:

```
$cates = DB::table('categories')
           ->select(DB::raw('categories.category_id, categories.category_title, categories.created_at, COUNT(task.task_id) AS counted_tasks'))
           ->leftJoin('tasks', 'categories.category_id', '=', 'tasks.task_cat_id')
           ->groupBy('categories.category_id, categories.category_title, categories.created_at')
           ->get();
```

Comment: It didn't work, and I had to turn off strict mode in config/database.php
Is that bad practice? or okay?

Comment: Do you mean that you still receive the error message?

Comment: nope, another error. but it is solved. thanks to you.